# How to draw a circle covering particular distance on map

Tags: java, android, google-maps-api-3

I am using GoogleMap fragment to show some location data using markers. What I want to do is, draw a circle with a radius of specific distance on map, so that the circle will cover certain area approximately on map. I am not sure where to start , I am already having a map displaying location data, from location data I can figure out at what distance those points are from centre location.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions()
    .center(new LatLng(37.4, -122.1))
    .radius(1000)); // In meters

// Get back the mutable Circle
Circle circle = myMap.addCircle(circleOptions);
```

For detailed info check : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes

Answer (score 1):

Use [GoogleMap Circle API](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle). You just need to pass the Required inputs and it's done. Follow link from example. e.g from docs , a simple code structure will look like this

```
Circle circle = map.addCircle(new CircleOptions() 
     .center(new LatLng(-33.87365, 151.20689)) // center point of map
     .radius(10000)  // radius of circle to cover on map
     .strokeColor(Color.RED)  //color of circle boundary 
     .fillColor(Color.BLUE)); //color of circle to fill ,
                              // make sure choose the light color close to transparent
```

Answer (score 1):

> Use this function where you need to pass `LatLng` as `paramater` when you call it.

```
private void drawCircle(LatLng point){

    CircleOptions circleOptions = new CircleOptions();

    // Specifying the center of the circle
    circleOptions.center(point);

    // Radius of the circle
    circleOptions.radius(20);

    // Border color of the circle
    circleOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLACK);

    // Fill color of the circle
    circleOptions.fillColor(0x30ff0000);

    // Border width of the circle
    circleOptions.strokeWidth(2);

    // Adding the circle to the GoogleMap
    googleMap.addCircle(circleOptions);

 }
```